# SVN Repository - CentOS 6.5

Tags: apache, svn, centos6.5

I'm trying to setup a SVN repository on my server. I've followed the routine steps to config the repository.By using "http://myip/svn" and After submitting the "Authentication Required" form (with a valid username and password), I've got:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
  <D:error>
       <C:error/>
       <m:human-readable errcode="13">Could not open the requested SVN filesystem</m:human-readable>
  </D:error>
```

I've created the repository using `svnadmin create repos` in "/home/svn/" directory. Then I used `chown -R apache.apache /home/svn/` to change the owner of the directory recursively.
I'm using the following "subversion.conf":

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /home/svn/repos
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "SVN Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/repos-users
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I've also used `chmod -R g+rws /home/svn/` but It didn't help. I think something with accessing apache to the svn directory is wrong.

Anyone has any idea how should I fix it?

Comment: I also tried multiple project on one repository settings in "subversion.conf" by `SVNListParentPath on` and `SVNParentPath /home/svn/repos` and I got: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
      <D:error><C:error/><m:human-readable errcode="13">
Can't open directory '/home/svn/repos': Permission denied
</m:human-readable></D:error>

Comment: `SVNParentPath /home/svn/repos` *is* error, if /repos already contain repository

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If you</strike>

> created the repository using svnadmin create repos in "/home/svn/"

then you must have `SVNPath /home/svn/`

AFAIK, all stock-Apaches **have not** statically linked modules and for pure DAV-SVN full set of modules (without authz) [is, according to docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic)

```
LoadModule dav_module         modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
```

You can also minimize Apache-related config and use stripped version of location for debug

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /home/svn/repos
</Location>
```

and also try to read repository locally, with `file:///` protocol - `svn ls` will be OK - (this way you'll detect is it problen in repo or in Apache's config some way)

Comment: I said I run the command `svnadmin create repos` in "/home/svn/" so my repository path is "/home/svn/repos/"

Comment: I think the problem comes from the different location path and svnpath. because when I change them to a same path, it works fine.